# Base CRM API Integration Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, rest, api, crm

I'm currently integrating Base CRM API on my App. I tried making an AJAX call for the API. I have my access token on the variable "token", just replaced it with some text on the code sample below:

```
var request;
var token = "token"
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET",'https://api.getbase.com/v2/accounts/self', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + token );
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
  alert(request.response);
 }
}
request.send();
```

After I run this, I'm getting a "404" error on Base's "https://api.getbase.com/v2/accounts/self" endpoint.